# Bootstrap - breaking point for screen resize doesn't trigger column resize

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, resize

I had two classes, for `md` size and `sm` size. `Sm` size was supposed to trigger the vertical stacking of columns.

Actually, **Bootstrap** has `xs` as its default breaking point, which is supposed to trigger the same effect, but nothing happens.

If I want `vertical` stacking, I have to set the `columns` to 12, and have no other **classes** for different screen sizes.

**The code is here:**

https://hastebin.com/uyaboxatuk.js

Comment: Please paste the code snippet directly into the post instead of the link, see: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You may have copied the wrong `<link>` & `<script>` tags for Bootstrap. Also watch your indentation. Keep in mind that you're better off putting your `<link>` tags first and then your `<script>` tags afterwards. Replace your `<link>` & `<script>` tags with what I have below in the exact order that are they are and it should work fine.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap Breakpoints specify the minimum screen size to apply the columns to.

For example `col-md` classes will only be applied to screen widths greater than 768px.

See the complete table of breakpoints and their sizes [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options).

Using your code as an example:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .row {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    .a {
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    .b {
      background-color: blue;
    }
    
    .c {
      background-color: green;
    }
    
    .d {
      background-color: gray;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-6khuMg9gaYr5AxOqhkVIODVIvm9ynTT5J4V1cfthmT+emCG6yVmEZsRHdxlotUnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="a row">
      <div class="b col-lg-2">large</div>
      <div class="c col-lg-4">large</div>
      <div class="d col-lg-6">large</div>
    </div>
    <div class="a row">
      <div class="b col-md-2">medium</div>
      <div class="c col-md-4">medium</div>
      <div class="d col-md-6">medium</div>
    </div>
    <div class="a row">
      <div class="b col-sm-2">small</div>
      <div class="c col-sm-4">small</div>
      <div class="d col-sm-6">small</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```